# Python General SOCKS server failure when assigning socket.socket

Tags: python, proxy, tor

I know similar questions have been asked several times:

[General SOCKS server failure with python tor but working from tor browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992581/general-socks-server-failure-with-python-tor-but-working-from-tor-browser)

[General SOCKS server failure when switching identity using stem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035413/general-socks-server-failure-when-switching-identity-using-stem)

[General SOCKS server failure while using tor proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31004104/general-socks-server-failure-while-using-tor-proxy)

I checked all related posts and googled a lot, but still got stuck.

I'm on Win10. I download Tor browser, run it and make sure it's on port 127.0.0.1:9150 with cmd `netstat -aon` in administrator.
Then I run the following example code in Python:

```
import socks
import socket
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9150)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
```

The last line `socket.socket = socks.socksocket` gives the Error message.
`socks.GeneralProxyError: Socket error: 0x01: General SOCKS server failure`

It's supposed to return a socket object which is assigned to socket.socket that opens a socket. Like this example:

https://deshmukhsuraj.wordpress.com/2015/03/08/anonymous-web-scraping-using-python-and-tor/

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?
Thanks.

**Update**

Thanks to drew010's answer, this code will work (with Tor browser running and it's port = 9150):

```
import requests

proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150',
    'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150'
}

url = 'http://icanhazip.com'

# request without Tor (original IP)
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.text)

# request with Tor (Tor IP)
r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
print(r.text)

# Force change IP
from stem.control import Controller
from stem import Signal

with Controller.from_port(port = 9151) as controller:
    controller.authenticate('mypassword')  
    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM) 

# Changed Tor IP
r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
print(r.text)
```

Note that we need to set password in torrc before.

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245748/multithreaded-crawler-while-using-tor-proxy

Comment: Thanks, it works. But is there any way to force IP change? Tor changes IP every couple of minutes.

Comment: You can force a change using the code in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33490484/tor-browser-new-ip-not-working/33507922#33507922  You will need to modify your torrc to set a `HashedControlPassword`, then connect using Stem Controller on port 9151 (for Tor Browser Bundle) and issue the `SIGNAL NEWNYM` command to change IP.  Bear in mind you can only do this once every 10-30 seconds, and Tor only has a limited number of usable Exit IP addresses.  If either of those answers were helpful, please consider up-voting them.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. Could you copy-paste your comments in an answer? So I can mark it as a solution and end this case.

Answer (score 0):

by doing "socket.socket = socks.socksocket" you're actually replacing each future socket objects to actually be a socksocket object, which means after that you can just use regular sockets and they will go through your socks proxy.